Is bootstrap.min.js CSP compatible?
I am importing the bootstrap.min.js library file in my AngularJS project. The problem arises when I add the following CSP line to my project:
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' http: https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"/>
  <customHeaders>
<httpProtocol>

I need to remove unsafe-eval from the policy. Therefore, I need to check whether the library file is CSP compatible or not, specifically checking if setTimeout, setInterval, eval, and Function are used without causing errors in the console.
What I have tried:
In the bootstrap.min.js library file (version 3.4), I noticed setTimeout is used 6 times, and setInterval is used once. I have tried to debug, and the first two setTimeout functions are working properly, but subsequent setTimeout calls are not being executed. I want to know if the library will be CSP compatible when I remove unsafe-eval from the policy.

To determine if bootstrap.min.js is compatible with a Content Security Policy (CSP) that removes 'unsafe-eval', we need to focus on how Bootstrap interacts with JavaScript's execution context, particularly regarding functions like setTimeout, setInterval, eval, and Function.
Check for Dependencies:

Some Bootstrap components (like modals or tooltips) may rely on jQuery or other libraries that could potentially use eval. Ensure those dependencies are also CSP-compliant.

Run your application with the CSP set to exclude 'unsafe-eval' and test all features that utilize Bootstrap.
Monitor console errors closely. If errors occur related to script execution, they will often indicate the offending function.
If bootstrap.min.js does not use eval, new Function(), or similar constructs, and if it calls setTimeout and setInterval directly, it should work fine without the 'unsafe-eval' directive. The key is to test and monitor for any CSP violations during runtime to confirm compatibility.

Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have tried to debug the application with the CSP set to exclude 'unsafe-eval'. While the first two setTimeout calls in bootstrap.min.js are working properly, subsequent setTimeout calls are not being executed, and I'm unable to verify if the library is fully CSP-compliant without the 'unsafe-eval' directive.
I have also checked for dependencies like jQuery to ensure they are CSP-compliant, but I still encounter issues. Are there any additional steps or tools you would recommend for diagnosing and resolving these CSP-related script execution issues?

I have never traced the source code of Bootstrap and I don't know why this problem occurs when subsequent setTimeout calls are not being executed.
